# Trouble with Nginx Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I'm fairly new to Nginx, and I'm working on converting an .htaccess file into something nginx can make sense of. Everything's working well (mostly) - I can pull up the homepage just fine. The problem is when I get to a post page.

think similar to wordpress, URLs like:

```
http://www.example.com/12/post-title-in-slug-form
```

Where 12 is the post id, and obviously that string is the post slug. I'm trying to parse those as two separate arguments (id & slug) and pass them into index.php like I was successfully doing in apache. I'm getting a 404 page, though, and have confirmed it is because of the rewriterule. Here's what the entire config file looks like, with only the website name changed (for privacy):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


        server {
                    listen 80;
                    server_name example.com;

                    access_log off;
                    error_log on;

                    # deny access to .XYZ files
                    location ~ /\. {
                        return 403;
                    }

                    location ~ sitemap\.xml {
                        return 301  http://example.com/sitemap.php;
                    }

                    location ~ .php$ {
                        # Here you have to decide how to handle php
                        # Generic example configs below
                        # Uncomment and fix up one of the two options

                        # Option 1: Use FastCGI
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    }

                    location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
                    }

                    location @router {
                        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/?(.*)?/?$ /index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 last;
                    }
        }

}
```

Please let me know if you can spot what's throwing it off when it comes to parsing the individual posts into ids and slugs and passing them. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to add a `/` just after the `^` of your regular expression, I think it's needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that, but had no more luck.

Comment: I think it is a very good idea to add the .htaccess file you want to convert to your question. Otherwise we don't know what exactly you want to convert, and might miss important edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you posted is indeed the COMPLETE config file, then the setup is missing something to handle PHP files as the regexp looks to be fine.

I actually think the config you posted cannot be the full one or that there is something fundamental going on as that config should have thrown errors and failed to load and also, since you mentioned that your PHP was loading fine, then it cannot be the posted config serving your website.

A better config is attached below:
FYI, `try_files ABC XYZ last;` is not valid syntax and you need at least two options in try_files. Anyway, fixed those in the posted config as well.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log off;
    error_log on;

    # deny access to .XYZ files
    location ~ /\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ sitemap\.xml {
        return 301  http://example.com/sitemap.php;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        # Here you have to decide how to handle php
        # Generic example configs below
        # Uncomment and fix up one of the two options

        # Option 1: Use FastCGI
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        #include fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        # Option 2: Pass to Apache
        # Proxy_pass localhost:APACHE_PORT

    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
    }

    location @router {
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/?(.*)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 last;
    }       
}
```

You will need to fix the PHP handling bit and choose which setup you want to implement.

I think though that you need to verify that you only have one instance of nginx running and that it is what is serving your site.

Comment: I see, this all makes much more sense to me now. It seems like there was a default config in sites-enabled that I backed up and removed. Perhaps that was adding additional configuration? Anyway, I've updated my config file now to match your example, and updated my original post to match my config file now. I've restarted nginx since the update. I also ran:

sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Homepage loads, calling index.php?id=8&slug=test also works, but /8/test still 404's.

Comment: Hopefully this will help. I've gotten logging working, so now we can see what's happening: http://pastebin.com/yPjY0t3J

Comment: Seems you are running a different conf file or another Nginx instance altogether. The bit that says `test location: "50x.html"` means the conf file has a 50x.html location block which the one you pasted above does not. Also, the bit that says `trying to use file: "=404"` etc means the conf file has `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` under `location /`. You need to sort out your installation. A lot of people use the sites-available and site-enabled ctructure and assume it is some Nginx default but to me, it is a pain in the neck and probably the cause of your issues. Possibly a rogue symlink

Comment: This ended up solving all my issues. I can't thank you enough for noticing this in my log ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `/` in the beginning and a `/` before index.php like this :

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/?(.*)?/?$ /index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 last;
```

Note i also used `$1` and `$2`

Comment: No luck with your suggestion, either, sadly. Thanks for the tips, though. I've incorporated the changes into my original question.

Comment: It worked for me.

Can you comment blocks containing `if (!-e $request_filename)` and see

Also can you post the proxy_pass section of your config file ?

Comment: Tried commenting out the request_filename lines as you suggested. Still getting the same result. I don't have a proxy_pass section. Is this something I need if I'm only running one page with no subdomains? I've pastebin'd my full config file (with only me website name changed for privacy) here: http://pastebin.com/zKdC72DJ

Comment: Yes since nginx does not process php files by itself so it needs to pass them to a php processor like fast_cgi. But I have questions so that I understand : In which directory are you putting your site's files?  If you invoke yoursite.com/index.php is it working fine ? You said your homepage is working, is that through an index.html file ?

Comment: So my site runs just out of the root folder. When I hit my homepage 'website.com/', it successfully loads up my index.php file. This file is also the one I would like to use to serve specific pages 'website.com/5/title-here'. This seems to be the problem, that somewhere between the regex matching and the rewrite, this rule isn't working: rewrite ^/?([0-9]+)/?(.*)?/?$ /index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 last;